# When quotient stacks (for nonsmooth group) are algebraic and related questions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, stacks, algebraic-stacks

Let $k$ be a field. Consider a group $k$-scheme $G$ and let $X$ be a $k$-scheme equipped with an action of $G$. Then one can define the quotient stack $[X/G]$. Objects of $[X/G]$ over $k$-scheme $T$ are pairs $(\pi, \alpha)$ such that $\pi:P\rightarrow T$ is a locally (with respect to fpqc topology) trivial $G$-bundle and $\alpha:P\rightarrow X$ is a $G$-equivariant morphism.

Now in Olson's book [Algebraic spaces and stacks](https://doi.org/10.1090/coll/062) in Example 8.1.12 the author assumes that $G$ is smooth in order to derive that the canonical map $X\rightarrow [X/G]$ is smooth and in result to infer that $[X/G]$ is an algebraic stack. It seems that the other part of his argument, which shows that the diagonal $\Delta_{[X/G]}:[X/G]\rightarrow [X/G]\times_k[X/G]$ is representable holds for any group $k$-scheme.

Here are some immediate questions.

1. Under what conditions on $G$ the stack $[X/G]$ is algebraic? Is smoothness essential?
2. If $G$ is affine over $k$, then is $\Delta_{[X/G]}$ representable by quasi-affine morphism of algebraic spaces? If not, then what one should impose on $X$ to know that this is the case?

Comment: If $G$ is not smooth, you should replace the étale topology by the fpqc topology in your definition of $[X/G]$.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Thank you. I edited my question.

Answer (score 6):

About 1. : no, smoothness isn't essential.

"Flat is enough" : De Jong's slogan to express this result due to M.Artin.

[https://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/wordpress/?p=1584](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Edejong/wordpress/?p=1584)

I quote :

"Given a flat, finitely presented group scheme $G$ over $S$ acting on a scheme $X$ over $S$, then the quotient stack $[X/G]$ is algebraic."

Comment: It is a beautiful theorem. Thank you.

Comment: @Slup You might find the following interesting: If I recall correctly, if $G$ is a locally finitely presented group scheme over a scheme $S$, then $BG :=[S/G]$ is algebraic if and only if $G$ is flat. A proof of this can be found on the Stacks Project (but might also have appeared on MO before).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I am mainly interested in schemes over fields, but it is very interesting and worth knowing. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is subsumed by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DLS, which talks about the case of algebraic spaces and also a further layer of 'relativeness': $X\to Y \to S$ and a group algebraic space $G\to Y$ acting on $X$ over $Y$.